# Can't see any changes (html, css) when running an Angular Project from IntelliJ

Tags: angular, gradle, jhipster, intellij-14

I have an Angular project for a web application which I am trying to run on IntelliJ. So I use Angular, Gradle, JHipster in my project.

I didn't work with IntelliJ until now, and I just cloned a project from BitBucket. Everything works perfect, but when I edit any html/css in the project, the changes doesn't appear in the browser. I don't think it's just for html/css as I also edited a component's code and the result doesn't show.

Is there any special command I should run?

Thank you!

I have tried reloading the project after I made the changes. I also tried to edit everything and then executing the "bootRun" command. I also commited all the changes to the Git.

Comment: Not quite understanding the question, you are supposed to run the `ng serve` command to start the server.

Comment: My server is running, I can work on my server on localhost:8080, but as I said, If I make any change in the project, I can't see the result in the browser (old version appears).

Comment: `ng serve` won't work for a JHipster project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In development, you're supposed to run both java backend on port 8080 using `gradlew` and frontend webpack dev server on port 9000 using `npm start`. Then in your browser, open http://localhost:9000

gradle with spring boot dev tools provides hot reloading for java, webpack provides hot reloading for Angular, HTML and CSS.

See [official documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular) for details, it should be also described in your project's README.md.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The problem was that I didn't run the ./gradlew before the npm start. So now I am seeing everything "live".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IntelliJ is the problem, webpack should pick up changes concerning the project no matter which editor you use. Consider using solutions provided in this issue thread: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610